# RabbitMq: Facing UndeclaredThrowableException in RPC call with RabbitMq

Tags: java, grails, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq with grails rabbitmq native plugin. I am trying to send an RPC call to another server where rabbitmq is installed, but as I tries sometimes **its working fine but many of the time it throws**:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

And, I am stuck with that, can anyone please help me out. The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.milestone.task.TaskProducerService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a87c72e8.sendCutycaptTask(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1108)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.milestone.TimelineService.createImageForPost(TimelineService.groovy:721)
at com.milestone.TimelineService.this$2$createImageForPost(TimelineService.groovy)
at com.milestone.TimelineService$this$2$createImageForPost$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
at com.milestone.TimelineService.$tt__createTimelineEntry(TimelineService.groovy:91)
at com.milestone.TimelineService$_createTimelineEntry_closure1.doCall(TimelineService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:62)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:59)
at com.milestone.TimelineService.createTimelineEntry(TimelineService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)`
```

Thanks!!

Comment: please post the code to reproduce the problem, and the stack trace of the error

Comment: @DerickBailey:- Thanks for reply i added stack trace please check thanks!